# How to get a Go library and run it in Docker?

Tags: linux, docker, go

I have this simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.16.6-buster
RUN wget -O - -q https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh | sh -s v1.45.2
RUN golangci-lint --version
```

When I build it, no matter how I change the second line above, I am always getting:

```
 > [3/3] RUN golangci-lint --version:
#6 0.331 /bin/sh: 1: golangci-lint: not found
```

What exactly I am doing wrong here?

If I try:

```
FROM golang:1.16.6-buster
RUN curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh\
    | sh -s v1.45.2

RUN bin/golangci-lint version
```

I get this detailed output:

```
docker build -t gotest .
[+] Building 0.9s (6/6) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 37B                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:1.16.6-buster                                                                                  0.5s
 => [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/golang:1.16.6-buster@sha256:f3923dc5a92a237db0f07a924a238a8a4a711e3b77a7b5bdb1b526e107dcb9d4                            0.0s
 => CACHED [2/3] RUN curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh    | sh -s v1.45.2                               0.0s
 => ERROR [3/3] RUN bin/golangci-lint version                                                                                                            0.2s
------
 > [3/3] RUN bin/golangci-lint version:
#6 0.214 /bin/sh: 1: bin/golangci-lint: not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c bin/golangci-lint version]: exit code: 127
```

Trying:

```
FROM golang:1.16.6-buster
RUN curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh\
    | sh -s v1.45.2

RUN /go/bin/golangci-lint version
```

Output:

```
docker build .
[+] Building 1.7s (7/7) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 212B                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 32B                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/golang:1.16.6-buster                                                                                  1.3s
 => [auth] library/golang:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                            0.0s
 => [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/golang:1.16.6-buster@sha256:f3923dc5a92a237db0f07a924a238a8a4a711e3b77a7b5bdb1b526e107dcb9d4                            0.0s
 => CACHED [2/3] RUN curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh    | sh -s v1.45.2                               0.0s
 => ERROR [3/3] RUN /go/bin/golangci-lint version                                                                                                        0.3s
------
 > [3/3] RUN /go/bin/golangci-lint version:
#7 0.276 /bin/sh: 1: /go/bin/golangci-lint: not found
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /go/bin/golangci-lint version]: exit code: 127
```

Comment: Did you try to download it in your local computer then copy it in the container with Copy command ?

Comment: @ZemmouriTarek This Docker should run as part of the CI on the server. There is no way to write code in Docker file that downloads the library locally then copy it to the container. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @LeeMaan they likely meant just to try and see what the results are - for example, if you can run the container locally, you can also use `docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash <container>` to start after a partial build or `docker exec -it <sha> /bin/bash` to enter the running container and explore (note also you may not have `bash`, but `sh` and may further still prefer [distroless](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless) once you have it working)

Answer (score 1):

`golangci-lint` is in `bin` directory :

```
FROM golang:1.16.6-buster

RUN curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh\
    | sh -s v1.45.2
RUN pwd
#RUN /go/bin/golangci-lint --version
```

build output :

```
$ docker build --pull --no-cache --tag golang .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  15.36kB
Step 1/3 : FROM golang:1.16.6-buster
1.16.6-buster: Pulling from library/golang
Digest: sha256:f3923dc5a92a237db0f07a924a238a8a4a711e3b77a7b5bdb1b526e107dcb9d4
Status: Image is up to date for golang:1.16.6-buster
 ---> 028d102f774a
Step 2/3 : RUN curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh    | sh -s v1.45.2
 ---> Running in 4700e3995fcc
golangci/golangci-lint info checking GitHub for tag 'v1.45.2'
golangci/golangci-lint info found version: 1.45.2 for v1.45.2/linux/amd64
golangci/golangci-lint info installed ./bin/golangci-lint
Removing intermediate container 4700e3995fcc
 ---> 03634ff2897c
Step 3/3 : RUN bin/golangci-lint --version
 ---> Running in f1348b5de5e2
golangci-lint has version 1.45.2 built from 8bdc4d3f on 2022-03-24T11:51:26Z
Removing intermediate container f1348b5de5e2
 ---> dc810407dc0d
Successfully built dc810407dc0d
Successfully tagged golang:latest
```

Comment: I'm getting the same `not found` output.

Comment: It looks like it installs to `./bin` and by default containers are bulid in `/`. so the RUN command needs to be `RUN /bin/golang-ci lint version`. If that doesn't work comment try adding a `cd /` at the beginning of the `curl`

Comment: Philippe, this is weird! I copied your code but getting the `detailed output` I just added to my question. Anything on my machine?

Comment: quick typo in your RUN; you're missing root `/` from `/bin`

Comment: @ti7 I fixed it to `RUN /bin/golangci-lint version` but still getting `#6 0.275 /bin/sh: 1: /bin/golangci-lint: not found`

Comment: Can you try the new `docker build ...` command ? You should not put `/bin`, because absolute path is `/go/bin/...`

Comment: Try updated version of `Dockerfile` -> `RUN /go/bin/golangci-lint version`

Comment: @Philippe tried `RUN /go/bin/golangci-lint version` with no gain. Also tried `docker build .` and reinstalled Docker but same output. Can't shake my head enough.

Comment: Can you paste new log ?

Comment: The guys who wrote the library said this should work `RUN wget -O- -nv https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golangci/golangci-lint/master/install.sh | sh -s -- -b /tmp v1.45.2` and  `RUN /tmp/golangci-lint version` but it didn't.

Comment: Typo, you have twice : `RUN RUN`

Comment: Fixed it. Same output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243910/discussion-between-lee-maan-and-philippe).

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked finally. No binary was getting downloaded due to versions mismatch. I upgraded Go to `1.16 0` and the linter to `1.45.2`. Also instead of `wget` I went for `go install` which works with this Go version. This got a binary downloaded in the default folder `/bin` and the CI job was fixed.

```
FROM golang:1.16.0-buster
RUN go install github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/cmd/golangci-lint@v1.45.2
RUN ./bin/golangci-lint --version
```